# What is this in my 5.4 triton?

Tags: ford, part-identification, f-150

Lookin' at my 04 Ford 150's 5.4L Triton. What is this engine component? I'm sure it has to do with the 4wd?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the anti lock brake module or ABS. While it is in you engine compartment it has nothing to do with the engine. The reason it has a 4x4 sticker on it is that ABS for 4x4 vehicles is slightly different than the ABS on regular two wheel drive vehicles.